# Is it possible to make a middle click open a Gmail thread in a new tab?

Tags: gmail, mouseevent

Before it went all ajaxy (a long time ago), you could just middle click an email to have it open in a new tab. Now, it's possible to ctrl+click, but all other links work with the middle click, so it would be nice to get that back somehow. Maybe with greasemonkey?

This in on Linux with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a webapp, and not about a programming question

Comment: Have you checked "settings", "settings", "labs"?